# Can we store instructions in dynamically allocated memory in C language?

Tags: c, heap-memory

Its well known that we can store `DATA` in dynamically allocated memory.

However, I was wondering if we can store `NEW INSTRUCTIONS` or `NEW FUNCTIONS` on the heap? Any real applications?

Preparing for interviews, so please bear with me if this isn't a sensible question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question is about C language, so the answer should be **no** — there is nothing in the language alone that defines anything like storing a function on the heap.

However, if we add knowledge of implementation details and OS (relocation tables, page protection, etc), then yes, it's possible. For example, custom dynamic code loaders (that do not use OS-provided DLL/SO loading) work this way.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, of course.  What do you think a [just-in-time compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) is?  Some [stack smashing attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow) work on a similar principle (executing code on the stack, rather than the heap).  This is one reason modern operating systems have protection against executing "data" pages.  (Legitimate dynamic code generators would have to disable such protection.)  See also the Wikipedia article on [self-modifying code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-modifying_code).

Comment: +1 for the only answer in a sea of "No, bad, stay away" that says "Well, yes, actually."

Comment: Agree. JVM provides mechanism of loading .class at runtime in stack and calling its function dynamically. But Aditya is asking adding function in heap specifically in C language

Answer (score 1):

When a program is loaded into memory, it is primarily organized into three areas of memory, called segments:

- the text segment
- stack segment
- heap segment

The text segment (also called the code segment) is where the compiled code of the program itself resides. Since 'NEW INSTRUCTIONS' or 'NEW FUNCTIONS' are to be known at compile time so we can not store them into Heap .

Hope this helps to answer your query .

Answer (score 1):

You surely can store anything as data, instructions included, but whether or not you will be able to actually execute those instructions and how depends a lot on the compiler and platform. You will have to dig into the low-level details of both to do it properly without crashing or hanging the program or the environment (for example, a primitive OS that lacks protection from applications).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859568/embed-assembler-to-manipulate-64-bit-registers-in-portable-c/7859813#7859813) is an example of storing the x86 BSWAP instruction as data in an array (not dynamically allocated, but that generally should not matter) and executing it. The example actually stores as data not the single BSWAP instruction but a complete C-callable routine that adheres to the compiler-mandated calling convention governing how the parameters are passed into it and the return values are returned from it.

The example is a 32-bit Windows application and since it is meant to run on Windows it also has to ensure that the region containing instructions is marked as readable and executable (the former is granted by the fact that they're in an array that can be read and written and the latter is ensured by calling the VirtualProtect() function to tell the OS to mark the region as executable, which is needed because the OS tries to protect us from accidental execution of code that can be malicious (e.g. untrusted data coming from the internet)).

Comment: Thanks a lot every one! Appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 0):

In general sense the answer is **No**; because code instructions has to be known at compile time.

**dynamically linked libraries** can be a closer match, to be liberal.