# Equivalent for GCC's naked attribute

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, freebsd

I've got an application written in pure C, mixed with some functions that contain pure ASM. Naked attribute isn't available for x86 (why? why?!) and my asm functions don't like when prologue and epilogue is messing with the stack. Is it somehow possible to create a pure assembler function that can be referenced from C code parts? I simply need the address of such ASM function.

Comment: You can do [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7859813/968261). Use the appropriate for your OS function to make the memory region executable.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just use `asm()` outside a function block. The argument of `asm()` is simply ignored by the compiler and passed directly on to the assembler. For complex functions a separate assembly source file is the better option to avoid the awkward syntax.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

asm("_one:              \n\
        movl $1,%eax    \n\
        ret             \n\
");

int one();

int main() {
        printf("result: %d\n", one());
        return 0;
}
```

PS: Make sure you understand the calling conventions of your platform. Many times you can not just copy/past assembly code.

PPS: If you care about performance, use [extended asm](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) instead. Extended asm essentially inlines the assembly code into your C/C++ code and is much faster, especially for short assembly functions. For larger assembly functions a seperate assembly source file is preferable, so this answer is really a hack for the rare case that you need a function pointer to a small assembly function.

Comment: `asm()` outside function blocks doesn't seem to work in `c99`.

Comment: @hauzer try `__asm` or `__asm__` instead of `asm`.

Comment: @hauzer A portable c99 program could have a global variable named `asm` that conflicts with this GCC extension. But names starting with two underscores are reserved for the implementation (e.g. GCC). So the GCC extension can use `__asm` and `__asm__` and still comply to the standard, but not `asm`.

Comment: I got the error `undefined reference to 'one'` and had to change the declaration to `int one() asm ("_one");` (on Linux).

Answer (score 7):

Good news everyone. GCC developers finally implemented **attribute((naked))** for x86. The feature will be available in GCC 8.

Comment: On a somewhat related note. GCC 7.1 added support for x86 interrupts with the `attribute((interrupts))` along with a related command line option `-mgeneral-regs-only`. The implementation leaves a bit to be desired but it isn't completed unimplemented anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Certainly, just create a `.s` file (assembly source), which is run through `gas` (the assembler) to create a normal object file.

Comment: If you use a `.S` suffix (capital S) your assembly code will be preprocessed by cpp as well.