# Multicompiler support for Inline Asm (x86)

Tags: c, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

For inline asm code I use `__asm` for vc++ compiler and `__asm__()` or `asm()` construct for gcc under linux. (intel/at&t syntax accordingly)

Is there a way to declare inline assembly (x86) in C for them both in a universal way?

P.S. An automated tool for incorporating both is also acceptable.

Comment: Assembler in source file has always been a compiler specific extension.

Comment: The simple answer is no.   A solution would be to put the assembly code in a macro and #ifdef it for each platform.

Comment: At that point it becomes easier to use YASM and link the asm code in separately. It wouldn't be inline, but it would work with GCC, MSVC, and others.

Comment: Not without an assembler library or an external tool. You could use machine code, though, like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7859813/968261).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the assembly in a macro and use the pre-processor to make the correct code.

```
#ifdef GCC
#define MY_ASM_CODE __asm() { blah blah blah}
#endif

#ifdef MSVC
#define MY_ASM_CODE __asm { blah blah blah }
#endif

int main(void)
{
  MY_ASM_CODE;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: dont you mean: `#define MY_ASM_CODE __asm` and `#define MY_ASM_CODE __asm()` ? So you can type: `MY_ASM_CODE {asm code here}` - though, i have never used asm code so i may be wrong...

Comment: @Rookie - No, the format of the asm code itself is also different for different compilers. As it is for different processors, and different modes (32/64 bit). There *is* a reason for writing code in C. :-)

Comment: Thanks. Though, it is not quiet what I was looking for - instead of a unified way to do both on the same 'strike', you basically suggest me to write both inlines separately which kinda miss my point.

Comment: You will have to write different code for each compiler as things like stack setup, variable access, which registers you can use etc will be different for each compiler (even same compiler, different version).

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative...

I presume you use Visual C because it's a Windows platform?

Why not use gcc for both Windows and Linux platforms?

Then it's the same source and same assembly format !